# Stranger Things Panel Outlet Connection

Tags: power, connector

I bought a Stranger Things light panel from Spirit Halloween a few years ago. It was the floor model, not the merchandise at the store. It had weird wiring and I lost the cord that plugs into the wall. Anyone know the name of the piece that will connect this to the wall? I can share more images if needed. Thanks![image]

Comment: Looks like a coaxial DC power connector.  If that's case, it means that there is an AC to DC power supply, similar to what is used to power a laptop, between the wall outlet and the power input to your sign.  You can measure the pin diameter and barrel diameter in mm to determine the mating power connector.  The voltage and current requirements depend on the the particular light panel.

Comment: That looks like a pretty standard large-ish barrel connector. If you take some measurements of the pin and the inner diameter of the hole you should be able to find something that fits. But unless you know the voltage your light panel wants, finding the correct size connector probably won't help you much.

Comment: Identifying the jack is the easy part, but without knowing the voltage and polarity, there's no way you can source a replacement.

Comment: It appears that the lights are powered by a low voltage DC power supply that plugs into the wall outlet. The part shown in the photograph is a barrel jack into which the barrel plug of the power supply would mate. Nothing much can be done unless the power requirement is known.

Answer (score 0):

This is YDJ-1130 or YDJ-1132 or similar.
https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=551